# Receiving an exception telling me the file being used in my code is in use by another process?

Tags: c#, exception

In my code which I wrote as practice for exception handling you put in two numbers. If an exception occurs it writes it to a log.txt and if an innerexception such as that file not existing occurs it creates the log file and then writes to it. Below is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication21
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your numerator!");
                    int numerator = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your denominator!");
                    int denominator = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    int Result = numerator / denominator;
                    Console.WriteLine("The result of the division of the two numbers {0} and {1} is: {2}", numerator, denominator, Result);
                }
                catch (FormatException formex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error format exception detected!");
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    if (File.Exists(@"C:\test files\log.txt"))
                    {
                        string dump = @"C:\test files\log.txt";
                        StreamWriter Streamwriter = new StreamWriter(dump);
                        Console.WriteLine("An unknown exception was detected and an error log has been dumped at {0}!", dump);
                        Streamwriter.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        Streamwriter.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                        Streamwriter.Close();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        throw new FileNotFoundException("Error file was not found!!!");

                    }
                }
            }

            catch(FileNotFoundException filex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: log file not found! Creating file!");
                File.Create(@"C:\test files\log.txt");
                    StreamWriter StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test files\log.txt");
                    StreamWriter.WriteLine(filex.GetType().Name);
                    StreamWriter.WriteLine(filex.InnerException.GetType().Name);
                    StreamWriter.Close();


            }
        }
    }
}
```

However when I run the code and test out the file creation system by deleting the txt and forcing the program to create a new one I get an exception telling me "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" and also due to this exception the errors are not being written to log.txt it simply produces a blank text file. From what I've observed the cause behind this is the Streamwriter class at the end of the code is causing the error. For some reason when the File.Create line is run even after the file is created for some reason it still has a hold of the file in the process thus not allowing StreamWriter to open it and write into it. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like below, the fileStream from File.Create is still not closed in your code. Hence, you get the error.

```
catch (FileNotFoundException filex) {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: log file not found! Creating file!");
            using (var fileStream = File.Create(@"C:\test files\log.txt")) {
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream)) {
                  streamWriter.WriteLine(filex.GetType().Name);
                  streamWriter.WriteLine(filex.InnerException.GetType().Name);                
              }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have file open somewhere to view the details and your program tries to write to it you will get that exception as it is not able to get lock on it. I have observed similar behaviour on windows 7 where you close the file but somehow OS still has lock on it and it takes few seconds before your program can get a lock on it. One thing I suggest is to use using block on your steam writer which will automatically flush the buffer at the end.

```
 if (File.Exists(@"C:\test files\log.txt"))
                    {
                        string dump = @"C:\test files\log.txt";
                        using(StreamWriter Streamwriter = new StreamWriter(dump))
                        {
                        Console.WriteLine("An unknown exception was detected and an error log has been dumped at {0}!", dump);
                        Streamwriter.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        Streamwriter.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                        Streamwriter.Close();
                     }
                    }
```

File.Create method already give you a file stream and you are trying to create a new one. You should use the file stream returned by File.Create method.

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
{
    //you can use the filstream here to write to file
}
```